# Tensor of a vector with itself and a matrix

Tags: tensor-products, matrix-equations, pseudoinverse

I have a vector  $\bf x$ with dimension $n$ by $1$. So  the tensor product is

$\bf{x} \ \otimes \bf x = xx^T$.

Then I have a singular symmetric matrix $\bf Q$ with 1 zero eigenvalue and  I end up with an equation

$\bf Q xx^T = \it{c} \bf{I}$,

where $c$ is some constant and $\bf I$ is an identity matrix.

Given $\bf Q$, can I recover the vector $\bf x$?

$\bf Q$ is singular so I can get its pseudoinverse. Does it make sense to get the square root of a pseudo inverse?

Another approach would be to have 
$\bf (Qx)(Qx)^T=\it{c}\bf{Q}$. So I'm thinking of getting the root of singular matrix.

Comment: I don't see how the equation $Qxx^T=cI$ can ever hold if $c\neq 0$. Taking any nonzero vector $y$ that is perpendicular to $x$, you have $$(Qxx^T)y=0$$ while $(cI)y=cy$...

Comment: From previous calculations, we had $xx^T =c Q^+$, where $Q^+$ is a pseudo inverse. So $Qxx^T =cI$ holds for such case.

Comment: But from $xx^T=cQ^+$, you cannot conclude that $Qxx^T=I$. $Q^+$ is only a **pseudo** inverse. You cannot conclude that $QQ^+=I$ in general, you can only conclude that if $Q$ is **invertible** in which case $Q^+=Q^{-1}$.

Comment: Yes, you do have a point. But for a case where $Qxx^T=I$ holds, is it possible to find vector $x$ given matrix $Q$?

Comment: My point is that $Qxx^T=I$ can never hold, as long as $n\geq 2$. No matter what you set $x$ to be equal to, there will always exist a nonzero vector $y$ which is perpendicular to it. And for that vector, $(xx^T)y=0$, meaning that $Qxx^T y = 0$, so $Qxx^T\neq I$ (no matter what $Q$ is equal to).

Comment: @Bingkat , since you are not an eagle, I think that it is better for you if you detail the "the previous calculation"  that led you to the formula $xx^T=cQ^+$; indeed, if $c\not= 0,Q\not=0$, then this formula implies $rank(Q^+)=1$ and therefore $rank(Q)=1$.

Comment: Since both $Q$ and $xx^T$ are singular then the image of their linear transformations do not span the entire space, but $Qxx^T=cI$ implies they do so we can conclude no such $Q$ exists. Whatever calculation you did to create it seems suspect at this point.